# Collecting results of @parallel for-loop via remotecall

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I use the `@parallel for` macro to run simulations for a range of parameters. Each run results in a 1-dimensional vector. In the end I would like to collect the results in a `DataFrame`.

Up until now I had always created an intermediate array and reduced the for-loop with `vcat`; then constructed the `DataFrame`. I thought it might also work to `push!` the result of each calculation to the master process via `remotecall`. A minimal example would look like

```
X=Float64[]

@sync @parallel for i in linspace(1.,10.,10)
        remotecall_fetch(()->push!(X,i),1)
       end
```

The result of which is consistently an array `X` with 9 not 10 elements. The number of dropped elements becomes larger as more workers are added.

This is on julia-0.6.1.

I thought I had understood julia's parallel computing structure, but it seems not.

What is the reason for this behavior? And how can I do it better and safely?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're triggering a race condition, though couldn't say where.

If you only need to return one value per iteration, I would suggest just using `pmap`:

```
pmap(linspace(1.,10.,10)) do i
    i
end
```

otherwise if each iteration could return multiple values, it would probably best to use [`RemoteChannel`s](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/parallel-computing#Channels-and-RemoteChannels-1).